# Possible to distribute an iOS app in different categories for particular countries?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, categories

As it turned out, Brazil has no Games category. We'd be happy if we could change the app's category, but only in Brazil.

Comment: Do we have to submit a whole new App available only in Brazil? With new bundle id, and the with the whole review process from the scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the only way to do this is to create a second app with a new name and bundle ID, e.g. MyApp - Brazil edition.

Apple generally don't like you doing this, so it's better just to use a category that works universally. But if you really have to have it be under games in the US, *AND* have it be available in Brazil, this is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Secondary Category:

from the [Developers Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf):

> The Primary category is the one that best describes your application,
> and is the category under which your application will be listed.
>
> The Secondary category will also provide an additional search term which
> may help users find your application. **The Secondary category is not
> required, however it is recommended since it will be used as a
> fall-back if the first is not available.** Note: The secondary category
> for Newsstand enabled apps will be automatically set to Newsstand and
> will not be editable in any state.

Comment: We do have set our secondary category (Entertainment), but still no hit in the brazilian AppStore.